# Julia programming - creating a tuple from indices in a set

Tags: tuples, julia

I have a set S={1,2,3}. I'm trying to create a tuple of the form (i,j,1) for which i and j are elements of S. When  S={1,2,3}, my set of tuples (say E)should be {(1,2,1),(2,1,1),(1,3,1),(3,1,1),(3,2,1),(2,3,1)}. I tried in the following way.

```
    for i in S
      for j in S
        E = Set()
        E = [(i,j,1),(j,i,1), i!=j]
        print(E)
      end
    end
```

But it doesn't give me the required result.What I'm getting is

> Any[(2,2,1),(2,2,1),false]Any[(2,3,1),(3,2,1),true]Any[(2,1,1),(1,2,1),true]Any[(3,2,1),(2,3,1),true]Any[(3,3,1),(3,3,1),false]Any[(3,1,1),(1,3,1),true]Any[(1,2,1),(2,1,1),true]Any[(1,3,1),(3,1,1),true]Any[(1,1,1),(1,1,1),false]

Can someone please help me to get the required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general solution could be:

```
julia> [(first(i)..., last(i)...) for i in Base.product(permutations(1:4, 3), [(5,6)])]
24×1 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64,Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1,2,3,5,6)
 (1,2,4,5,6)
 (1,3,2,5,6)
 (1,3,4,5,6)
 (1,4,2,5,6)
 (1,4,3,5,6)
 (2,1,3,5,6)
 (2,1,4,5,6)
 (2,3,1,5,6)
 (2,3,4,5,6)
 (2,4,1,5,6)
 (2,4,3,5,6)
 (3,1,2,5,6)
 (3,1,4,5,6)
 (3,2,1,5,6)
 (3,2,4,5,6)
 (3,4,1,5,6)
 (3,4,2,5,6)
 (4,1,2,5,6)
 (4,1,3,5,6)
 (4,2,1,5,6)
 (4,2,3,5,6)
 (4,3,1,5,6)
 (4,3,2,5,6)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve what you want with a [list comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/variables-and-scoping/#man-for-loops-scope):

```
[(i,j,1) for i in S for j in S if i != j]
```

Note that this gives you an array, but you can then pass this onto a set constructor; alternatively you can use a '[generator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/#generator-expressions)' directly:

```
Set( (i,j,1) for i in S for j in S if i != j )
```

---

**What was I doing wrong though?**

This part of the code:

```
E = Set()
E = [(i,j,1),(j,i,1), i!=j]
```

doesn't do what you think it does. I think you intended `E` to be 'instantiated' as a 'set' object, to which you were then expecting to "append" elements by "assigning" them to E. (also, there's the issue of why you expected a normal element to act as a selection test, but whatever).

But clearly this doesn't work, because every time you *assign* something to `E`, you're replacing its previous contents with [a reference to] a *new* object.

If you wanted to approach this by carefully 'appending' your desired elements one-by-one, this *is* possible, but you should have done it like this:

```
E = Set()
for i in S, j in S
  if i != j
    push!(E, (i,j,1), (j,i,1));
  end
end
```

<sub>(also note julia's special 'nested for loop' syntax here)</sub>